# override background opacity for images

Tags: html, css, image, transparency, opacity

I would like to change the opacity of my imaage. Now it just inherits its mother's opacity setting but I would like to make it less transparent. In clear words: at http://quaaoutlodge.com there's the "Jack Sam's Restaurant & Lounge" picture on the right side. I want to make that less transparent than the background. If I change the opacity setting of .rteright I seem to only be able to make it more transparent but not less...
How can I achieve what I want?
Please advise!
The code: Where the "pageBorder" is sert tio opacity 0.7

```
<div id="pageBorder" class="noborder">
<p class="rteright" style=""><a href="http://quaaoutlodge.com/content/jack-sams-restaurant-and-lounge"><img alt="Jack Sam's Restaurant and Lounge" src="http://quaaoutlodge.com/sites/default/files/jack-sams-lounge--3-_0.jpg" style="text-align: right; width: 200px; height: 133px; float: right; border:1px #000 solid;" /><em>Jack Sam's Restaurant &amp; Lounge</em></a></p>
</div>
```

Thank you,
Ron

Comment: Please post the **relevant code** so that we can quickly get a good idea of the problem.

Comment: Please see: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/) for reasons why your post may need improvement.

Comment: Thanks, I added some code, hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rgba()` values to make only the background of an element transparent. `opacity` makes all of the child elements transparent, not just the parent.

Something like:

```
background: rgba(128,102,51,0.5);
```

The values are as follows:

```
background: rgba(red, green, blue, opacity);
```